# Php If Statement isnt giving out right echo - logical error

Tags: php, mysql

I have this if statement

```
if('Shift' % 60 < 15) {
    echo "< td >" . intval($row['shift'] / 60) . ':' . '00' . ' - '. intval($row['shift2'] / 60) . ':' . $row['shift2'] % 60 . "< /td >";
}elseif('shift' % 60 >= 15){
    echo "< td >" . intval($row['shift'] / 60) . ':' . $row['shift'] % 60 .' - '. intval($row['shift2'] / 60) . ':' . $row['shift2'] . '00' . "< /td >";
}elseif('shift2' % 60 < 15){
    echo "< td >" . intval($row['shift'] / 60) . ':' . $row['shift'] % 60 .' - '. intval($row['shift2'] / 60) . ':' . $row['shift2'] . '00' . "< /td >";
}elseif('shift2' % 60 >= 15){
    echo "< td >" . intval($row['shift'] / 60) . ':' . '00' .' - '. intval($row['shift2'] / 60) . ':' .   $row['shift2'] % 60  . "< /td >";
}
```

i have a database where times are saved as minutes, e.g.: 10:30 is saved as 630.
Since i have put them out in a table i need to convert them back into time by using %, my problem right now is that, if want to put them out "10:30 - 19:00" is being put out as "10:30 - 19:0" and if the time changes the there is always missing a zero. and its giving out the wrong time it should be "10:30 - 19:00" but it is "10:00 - 19:00" I tried it by using a if but somewhere is a logical error.

Thx in advance

Comment: If it's always a zero missing, why not just  ` ."0"` at the end of the output?

Comment: forgot to add its giving out the wrong time it should be "10:30 - 19:00" but its "10:00 - 19:00"

Comment: @Jakare can you read your code?

Comment: Why do you at the if statement write only `'shift'` but at the rest of the code you write `$row['shift']`?

Answer (score 3):

You are testing `Strings` not variable in your `if` statements

I assume that it should be `if($row['shift'] % 60 < 15)`